# Samsung account not showing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Could anyone assist me with enabling my Samsung account on my S3. Each time I pressed buy in video hub I got this message on my phone: 
"Your Samsung account has been disabled. Enable it by going to Applications manager > Samsung account"

I followed the instruction but there in no Samsung account among the list to enable. I tried to setup the account through "Add account>Server >sync server giving the web address, login in ID and password. Everything was accepted but still giving me same message. My Samsung account is running well on web.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the app 'Samsung Account' has been disabled, re-enable it by using the following:

Settings > Application Manager > Use the right-most panel by panning right to the Heading 'All'. Scroll up all the way to the 'Disabled' part of the list, which is at the bottom, click 'Samsung Account' > Enable.

UPDATE: expanded instructions for clarity:
The Application Manager is initially in the 'Downloaded' panel, and the column header is underlined. To the right is the 'Running' panel, and to the far right is the 'All' panel. Disbled apps are at the bottom of the 'All' panel. Select the app you want to re-enable.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanations. I got all your instructions correctly however there is no disabled app at the bottom of the All panel.

Comment: You can see if your Disabled app list is active, by disabling some useless app that came with the phone, maybe one of the live wallpapers 'Windy weather', which should appear near the bottom of the 'All' panel. Select and disable it. This will provide an example of how a disabled app is marked in this list. Do this only if you believe your list is working properly. You can re-enable it if you want it back.

Comment: It worked as I disabled and re-enabled the Windy weather app. Truly I know how it works now. I have never done this before and there are no apps disabled under All panel of my phone.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -4):

1. [Go]
2. Application Manager
3. Run All
4. [Press Left Button of smart phone for menu]
5. [menu will show on screen]
6. Select option to enable all application